# WPF Styling Colors

Tags: wpf, staticresource

I want to do something like this:

**Resource Dictionary**

```
<Color x:Key="clrPrimary">#5381ac</Color>
<Color x:Key="clrSecondary">#20558a</Color>

<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="myGrid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource clrPrimary"/>
</Style>
```

**Getting Exception:**

```
'#FF5381AC' is not a valid value for property 'Background'.
```

Having trouble nailing it down, can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Background` is a `Brush`, not a `Color`. Your best bet is to define your "Primary" and "Secondary" resources as brushes rather than colours.

Pretty sure you could even base the brushes off your existing colours.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{StaticResource clrPrimary}" />
...
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

The background property needs a brush to work.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="clrPrimary" Color="#5381ac" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Background Property is of type `System.Windows.Media.Brush`, not a Color.